# Would group by in LINQ make this faster? Is it even possible?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ data table that looks like this:

```
numberColumn    Value
1               3
4               1
30              6
20              10
50              5
```

I also have a list of ranges that looks like this (can have any amount of ranges)

```
Ranges
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 0
        upperRangeExclusive = 10
        average = null
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 10
        upperRangeExclusive = 40
        average = null
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 40
        upperRangeExclusive = 100
        average = null
```

I need to calculate the average value for each range of numberColumn in a fast way (my real data is very large. 10s of thousands of rows, 100+ ranges). In the above example, it should look like this:

```
Ranges
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 0
        upperRangeExclusive = 10
        average = 2
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 10
        upperRangeExclusive = 40
        average = 8
    range
        lowerRangeInclusive = 40
        upperRangeExclusive = 100
        average = 5
```

Right now I just have something like this, but it's very slow. Is this horrible unoptimized, or is there just going to be slow no matter what?:

```
var table = GetTable();
foreach (var range in Ranges)
{
    range.Average = table.Where(n => n.numberColumn >= range.lowerRangeInclusive &&
                              n.numberColumn < range.upperRangeExclusive)
                   .Select(x => x.Value).Average();
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What is a linq table? You mean a `DataTable` or some custom object? How many rows? And define "slow", how slow are we talking about?

Comment: It started as a DataTable, but I did this (not sure what the term for it is) someTable.Select(
                        n => new
                        {
                            numerColumn=thing; value = otherThing;
                        }).ToList();

Comment: I believe that it's slow because you're using DataTable. I would use SqlDataReader instead.

Comment: Without defining "slow" or how large your data set is, it is hard to provide much assistance.

Comment: Are all of your ranges continuous on the bounds as in your example? Can you fit all of your data into memory?

Comment: Yes, the ranges are continuous, and yes it will fit in memory.

Comment: You're looking at every row in the DataTable several times, once for each `range`. You could put ("bin") each `Value` into a list corresponding to a range and then find the average of each of those lists.

Comment: What do you mean by put ("bin")?

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what "very slow" means to you. I binned the data into lists, each of which corresponds to a range. For 100,000 items in 200 ranges, it took under a second to process on my computer.

LINQ may be elegant and quick to write, but it is not always the fastest way to process data.

If this code doesn't help you understand what is meant by "binning", perhaps [Histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Mathematical_definition) will help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

static class Module1
{

    const int NUMBERCOLUMNMAX = 1000;
    const int VALUEMAX = 100;
    const int SAMPLEDATASIZE = 100000; // how many rows to populate the DataTable with.
    const int NBINS = 200; // equivalent to quantity of ranges

    static Random rand = new Random();
    static DataTable dt;

    static List<Range> ranges;

    public class Range
    {
        public int LowerRangeInclusive { get; set; }
        public int UpperRangeExclusive { get; set; }
        public double Average { get; set; }
    }

    public static DataTable GetData()
    {
        // create DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dcNum = new DataColumn
        {
            ColumnName = "numberColumn",
            DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        };
        DataColumn dcVal = new DataColumn
        {
            ColumnName = "Value",
            DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        };
        dt.Columns.Add(dcNum);
        dt.Columns.Add(dcVal);

        // populate DataTable
        for (int i = 1; i <= SAMPLEDATASIZE; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = rand.Next(1, NUMBERCOLUMNMAX + 1);
            dr[1] = rand.Next(1, VALUEMAX + 1);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;

    }

    public static List<Range> GetRanges()
    {
        ranges = new List<Range>();
        int nRanges = NBINS;

        for (int i = 0; i < nRanges; i++)
        {
            Range thisRange = new Range
            {
                LowerRangeInclusive = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(NUMBERCOLUMNMAX) * i / nRanges)),
                UpperRangeExclusive = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(NUMBERCOLUMNMAX) * (i + 1) / nRanges))
            };
            ranges.Add(thisRange);
        }

        return ranges;

    }

    public static void SetAverages(List<Range> ranges, DataTable dt)
    {
        int nRanges = ranges.Count;
        List<int>[] bins = new List<int>[nRanges];

        for (int i = 0; i < nRanges; i++)
        {
            bins[i] = new List<int>();
        }

        int numCol = dt.Columns["numberColumn"].Ordinal;
        int valCol = dt.Columns["Value"].Ordinal;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nRanges; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr[numCol]) >= ranges[i].LowerRangeInclusive && Convert.ToInt32(dr[numCol]) < ranges[i].UpperRangeExclusive)
                {
                    bins[i].Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[valCol]));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //TODO: Do something meaningful in the case where ranges(i).Count == 0 instead of the average being zero.
        for (int i = 0; i < nRanges; i++)
        {
            if (bins[i].Count > 0)
            {
                ranges[i].Average = bins[i].Average();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Init...");
        dt = GetData();
        ranges = GetRanges();
        Console.WriteLine("done.");

        // Show ranges
        //foreach (Range r in ranges)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,4} {1,5}", r.LowerRangeInclusive, r.UpperRangeExclusive));
        //}

        // Show datarows
        //for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,5}", dt.Rows[i][0], dt.Rows[i][1]);
        //}

        //Time it so that comparisons can be made to other methods.
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        SetAverages(ranges, dt);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} rows processed in {1} bins in {2}ms.", dt.Rows.Count, NBINS, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        // Show the results
        foreach (Range r in ranges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0},{1}): {2}", r.LowerRangeInclusive, r.UpperRangeExclusive, r.Average));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

P.S. I originally wrote it in VB and used an on-line converter to get the C#, so there might be some things which can be optimised for C# which I am not aware of.